# Zooming and translating unity camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

In my scene I have a camera as a child of an empty game object. In my script I have the ability to rotate around the parent object, translate the parent object, and zoom my camera by moving it on the Z axis.

However, what I'm wanting is to have my cameras Y position remain the same when the parent is moved. In the sample I have posted below, I have worked out how to achieve this. But I am no longer able to zoom in and out anymore.

I've been looking at this for a while now, and I've a feeling its something daft I'm not doing. But could someone take a look over my zooming and translating methods to see what I'm doing wrong / missing?

```
// Pinch fingers to zoom camera
// Will move camera on the Z access
void CameraZoom ()
{

    // if fingers moved certain distance apart, zoom
    float dot = Vector2.Dot (Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition.normalized, Input.GetTouch (1).deltaPosition.normalized);

    if (dot < -fingerDistance) 
    {

        // Store both touches.
        Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch (0);
        Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch (1);

        Vector2 touchZeroPrevPos = touchZero.position - touchZero.deltaPosition;
        Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;

        float prevTouchDeltaMag = (touchZeroPrevPos - touchOnePrevPos).magnitude;
        float touchDeltaMag = (touchZero.position - touchOne.position).magnitude;
        float deltaMagnitudeDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - touchDeltaMag;

        if (useFieldOfView == true) 
        {
            cam.fieldOfView += deltaMagnitudeDiff * perspectiveZoomSpeed;
            // Clamp the field of view to make sure it's between 0 and 180.
            cam.fieldOfView = Mathf.Clamp (cam.fieldOfView, 0.1f, 179.9f);
        }
        else if (useFieldOfView == false) 
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x , transform.position.y , transform.position.z );
            transform.Translate (0, 0, deltaMagnitudeDiff * perspectiveZoomSpeed);
        }
    }
}

void MoveCamera ()
{

    Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition;
    // this is the line keeping my camera stationary on the Y axis
    transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x , cameraCurrentYHeight , transform.position.z );
    transform.parent.Translate (-touchDeltaPosition.x * speed, 0, -touchDeltaPosition.y * speed);


    if(transform.parent.position.y <= yMovementLowestValue)
    {
        transform.parent.position = new Vector3(transform.parent.position.x, yMovementLowestValue, transform.parent.position.z);
    }
}
```

My original idea was to take a "snap shot" of the cameras current height, when the parent is moving. Then, as the parent moves, simply keep the camera at this constant height. I do this by checking that two touches have been registered, and that they are stationary, then when the move, the zoom and movement methods are called. All of this, can be found in my update method as follows:

```
    if (Input.touchCount == 2 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved && Input.GetTouch (1).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) 
    {
        CameraZoom ();
        MoveCamera ();  
        takeSnapShot = false;

    }


    if(Input.touchCount == 2 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Stationary && Input.GetTouch(1).phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
    {

        takeSnapShot = true;
    }

    if(takeSnapShot == true)
    {
        cameraCurrentYHeight = cam.transform.position.y;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dot product of two normalized vectors will always give you 1

```
float dot = Vector2.Dot (Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition.normalized, Input.GetTouch (1).deltaPosition.normalized);
```

I think what you meant to do is:

```
float dot = (Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition - Input.GetTouch (1).deltaPosition).sqrMagnitude;
```

Also, since you are using the square magnitude, i'm sure because you are concerned with performance, you want to compare the two squares together in the `if` statement as well, like so:

```
if (dot < fingerDistance * fingerDistance)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm just trying this and getting the following error: Operator `-' cannot be applied to operands of type `UnityEngine.Vector2' and `UnityEngine.Touch' on where the dot is being calculated

Comment: Yes, i forgot to add `.deltaPosition` on the second one

Comment: Thank you. I've implimented your recommendations, but I am still unable to zoom and translate. If I take out  'transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x , cameraCurrentYHeight , transform.position.z );' then everything works as normal. But I need the Y positon of my camera to remain the same when it moves

Comment: You shouldnt be manipulating the `position`, and then translating it's `parent` in the same frame. I don't know exactly what you are trying to do by that, so unfortunately i cannot provide a solution or alternative, but maybe you meant to change the `localPosition` instead?

Comment: Also if you don't have anything directly manipulating the `y` value of position, you can rest assured that it will not be changed by anything else unless it has a `RigidBody` attatched. So you don't have to keep setting it.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is when two fingers touch the screen and move around close togther, the camera follows, when they seperate, zoom out. This would be simpler if I could use 3 fingers, but I'm stuck needing to use two for both

Comment: I understand that, but i'm saying by manipulating the `position` *and* `parent.position` in the same frame, i don't know why exactly because i cannot see your hierarchy, but to me it doesn't make sense at first glance.

Comment: Im sure you either meant to manipulate the `localPosition` instead of `position`, or you meant to do `parent.position` for both

Answer (score 0):

Why not move the camera out of the emptyGameObject and just update the x and z position of the camera with the emptyGameObject x and z.

```
public GameObject control;    
..

control.transform.Translate (-touchDeltaPosition.x * speed, 0, -touchDeltaPosition.y * speed);
transform.position = new Vector3(control.transform.position.x, transform.position.y, control.transform.position.z);
```

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer